# How to pass data from Container to other Container in Pageview flutter

Tags: flutter

I make one page that page have Pageview to display many of containers. Now my problem I need to pass data from Container-1 to Container-2 as text or number.. etc. At the same time, the user moves from the first Pageview to the second Pageview.

This is my page code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(TestClass());


class TestClass extends StatefulWidget {


  @override
  _TestClassState createState() => _TestClassState();
}

class _TestClassState extends State<TestClass> {
  final pagecontroller = PageController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(home:Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("PageView Demo"),
      ),
      body: PageView(
        controller: pagecontroller,
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,

        children: [
          Center(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  child: Text(
                    "First Container-1",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 28),
                  ),
                ),


                RaisedButton(
                  child: Text(
                    'Navigate to Container-2 >>',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {

                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Center(
            child: Container(
              child: Text(
                "Second Container-2 ",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 28),
              ),
            ),
          ),

        ],
      ),
    ),
    );
  }
}
```

How I can pass the data between it ? any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think , you should create another page . In second page you should create a variable (int, String , bool or whatever you want ) .

Then You should write this code in first container

```
GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder:   (context) => Container2(
                      value : yourValue
                    )));
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    width: 50, height:  50,
                    child: Text(
                      "First Container-1",
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 28),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```